# Create a CSS animation that replicates a race-car countdown

Tags: html, css

I want to create a simple animation that takes each > sign and treats it like a racetrack or stoplight. AKA I would like the >(red)..(yellow)..>(green) with the .. representing .5 seconds in between. Can I do this is CSS3? If not how could I go about doing this. Any help appreciated.

```
<p id="pipes"> >>> </p>

#pipes:hover{

}
```

Comment: not sure why downvoted. Im genuinely curious and new to animations

Comment: you may wanna use jquery for this

Comment: Curiosity is fine, however on SO you need to show what you've tried, otherwise you're just asking someone to do all your work for you.

Comment: alright the hounds are out to get me. I thought SO was for asking questions and receiving answers. I didnt realize I would be attacked for a simple question. I will go on W3 and close this post.

Comment: Please don't say you're being attacked. No one attacked you. And please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though this got downvoted, I thought this would be a fun exercise. Pay attention to the transition-delay particularly.

```
<ul class="pipes">
    <li> > </li>
    <li> > </li>
    <li> > </li>
</ul>

.pipes {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.pipes li {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block;
    transition: color .5s ease;
}


.pipes:hover li:nth-of-type(1) {
    color: red;
    transition-delay: .5s;
}

.pipes:hover li:nth-of-type(2) {
    color: yellow;
    transition-delay: 1s;
}

.pipes:hover li:nth-of-type(3) {
    color: green;
    transition-delay: 1.5s;
}
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/06ywu8nt/